# Gdalwarp for terrain correction in SAR image

Tags: gdalwarp, gdal-translate, rgdal, gdal-merge

I am new to the gdal utility. Using DEM data of the Moon, I am trying to perform terrain correction on SAR images.

Here is gdal commandline code ```
!gdalwarp -multi -wo NUM_THREADS=ALL_CPUS -co NUM_THREADS=ALL_CPUS --config GDAL_CACHEMAX 1536 -wm 1536 -rpc -to RPC_DEM=ldec_1281.tif -of GTiff  -ts 4000 4000 hh.tif outFile.tif

```
When I run this command I am getting the following error 
ERROR 1: Unable to compute a RPC based transformation between pixel/line and georeferenced coordinates for hh.tif.

Does anyone help me?
```

Comment: Do you get any more information by adding `--debug on` to your command?

Comment: This is the only message ERROR 1: Unable to compute a RPC based transformation between pixel/line and georeferenced coordinates for hh.tif.